# How to create a complex type dict object

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to create a dict reading the date from a file for further processing but unable to get the code to work. I am working in python and new to this language. My file data looks like this:

```
Name1   L1  11  P27 41
Name1   L1  13  P27 43
Name1   L2  85  O60 125
Name1   L2  07  O60 107
Name1   L2  68  O60 118
Name1   L2  17  O60 117
Name1   L2  92  O60 192
Name2   L1  04  O60 84
Name2   L1  19  Z91 139
Name2   L2  32  Z91 332
```

Now, I want to create the dict object as:

```
{
    'Name1':[L1,(11,13),(41,43),P27],[L2,(85,07,68,17,92),(125,107,118,117,192),O60],
    'Name2':[L1,(19),(139),Z91],[L2,(32),(332),Z91]
}
```

Comment: what is `L1` in your dict, exactly? it is written as a variable name, but it is not. I guess you want a string there.

Comment: what you have provided is not a valid `dict`

Comment: yes L1 is sample data not a variable. I want to transform the file data, basically columns to rows but that too selectively. L1 has two cols both of them are converted into rows like (11,13) and (41,43) receptively. but  note that 4th col data is not repeated in the transformation row.

Comment: @UserSubir, why do you remove one of the Name2,L1 values from the input? O60 one is not in the output.

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake both should be O60.

Comment: Is there any way to find Name1, L1 details? Basically, L1 is the test type say Maths where [11,13] and [42,43] are term marks by attempts respectively and P27 is the test paper grading like complex to easy. Now, I want to find Name1->L1 test details "['L1', ['11', '13'], ['41', '43'], 'P27']". Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `defaultdict` is helpful for this sort of problem, it allows you to append to a dictionary entry, if an entry doesn't exist yet, it will append to an empty list and place it there, instead of throwing an exception as usual. Here's how I used it to process your data:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)
with open("input.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip().split()
        namelist = d[line[0]]
        try:
            idx = [x[0] for x in namelist].index(line[1])
        except:
            idx = -1
        if len(namelist) and idx >= 0:
            namelist[idx][1].append(line[2])
            namelist[idx][2].append(line[4])
        else:
            namelist.append([line[1], [line[2]], [line[4]], line[3]])

print d
>>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, 
{'Name2': [
    ['L1', ['04', '19'], ['84', '139'], 'O60'], 
    ['L2', ['32'], ['332'], 'Z91']
], 
'Name1': [
    ['L1', ['11', '13'], ['41', '43'], 'P27'], 
    ['L2', ['85', '07', '68', '17', '92'], ['125', '107', '118', '117', '192'], 'O60']
]})
```

Comment: Is there any way to find Name1, L1 details? Basically, L1 is the test type say Maths where [11,13] and [42,43] are term marks by attempts respectively and P27 is the test paper grading like complex to easy. Now, I want to find Name1->L1 test details "['L1', ['11', '13'], ['41', '43'], 'P27']". Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

To process the lines, use

```
with open(filename) as file_handle: # open your file
    for line in file_handle:        # iterate over lines
        chunks = line.split()       # extract parts of the lines
        ...
```

Now `chunks` will contain parts of your line.

You should build a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), or even better [`defaultdict(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and insert the elements there.

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` doesn't exactly work straight out of the box here, since OP wants  something like `[L1,(11,13),(41,43),P27]`

Comment: I am able to read the file but while creating the dict transformation i am failing.

Comment: @jamylak: yeah, I wanted to give some hints rather full working code

Answer (score 1):

```
h=dict()
with open("input") as ifile:
    for l in ifile:
        n,c1,c2,c3,c4=l.split()
        # now, n=Name1   c1=L1  c2=11  c3=P27 c4=41
        # create a dict for h['Name1'] if it doesn't exist
        if n not in h: h[n] = dict()
        # create a row for h['Name1']['L1'] if it doesn't exist
        if c1 not in h[n]: h[n][c1] = [ [], [], [] ]
        # now we have h['Name1]['L1] = [ [], [], [] ]
        # add items to each column if that item does not exist there
        if c2 not in h[n][c1][0]: h[n][c1][0].append(c2)
        if c3 not in h[n][c1][1]: h[n][c1][1].append(c3)
        if c4 not in h[n][c1][2]: h[n][c1][2].append(c4)

for hh in h:
    for hhh in h[hh]:
        print hh, hhh, h[hh][hhh]
```

**Output**

```
Name2 L2 [['32'], ['Z91'], ['332']]
Name2 L1 [['04', '19'], ['O60', 'Z91'], ['84', '139']]
Name1 L2 [['85', '07', '68', '17', '92'], ['O60'], ['125', '107', '118', '117', '192']]
Name1 L1 [['11', '13'], ['P27'], ['41', '43']]
```

After this you can freeze this structure into some tuple form as you like.

Comment: I am not very sorry but i am not able follow your answer. Please add few explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I will also try work on this solution . you guys are too good and very helpful!